# Pandas gives different results for different machines

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, stat

When I upgraded from numpy 1.9 to 1.10 I started to see that the following regression model gives different results on different machines with the same hardware configuration:

```
fitted_model = pd.ols(y=lhs_unpickled, x=rhs_unpickled, intercept=False)
print fitted_model.beta
```

`lhs_unpickled` and `rhs_unpickled` look like this:

```
> lhs_unpickled[1:5]
2008-04-24 00:18:00+00:00   -0.465517
2008-04-24 00:33:00+00:00   -0.519584
2008-04-24 00:48:00+00:00   -0.607410
2008-04-24 01:03:00+00:00   -0.705983
Freq: 15T, Name: AI_Index, dtype: float64

> rhs_unpickled[1:5]
                                CPM       XQH       FOD        EX
2008-04-24 00:18:00+00:00 -0.301556  0.148582  0.079320 -0.707586
2008-04-24 00:33:00+00:00 -0.274421  0.071747  0.130182 -0.659409
2008-04-24 00:48:00+00:00 -0.273960 -0.001447  0.148643 -0.703215
2008-04-24 01:03:00+00:00 -0.238426 -0.008732  0.130801 -0.698489
```

Is there something specific about this `pd.ols()` function which results in this inconsistent behavior when using numpy 1.10?

Comment: Are you sure `y` and `x` should have the same value as you wrote (i.e. `lhs_unpickled`) ? Because then `beta=1` no matter what

Comment: @RafaelC I just updated that..

Comment: Hm, so your typo was only here in this question? Im thinking you probably have a typo in your codes, or a difference in data. Results should be the same.. Also, note that `pd.ols` has been deprecated, don't know if theres some incompatibility in there

Comment: @RafaelC yes, the typo is only in this question. What should I use instead of pd.ols instead? thank you.

Comment: This is very broad. There is no reproducable example and many things are missing (OS, numpy-setup and so on; probably not relevant, but even BLAS alone could induce indeterminism). Additionally it's unclear to me what exactly happens. Are those results deterministic? Are they not? Did statsmodels-version change too (should be the underlying code in use)?